# Cannot use a variable if it is used in a DEF, under an IF condition

Tags: python, function, variables

So I have a file from which I import another file, in the main file I need to use a variable that is in another file and is under DEF function and IF condition.
But every time I get that there is no such variable.

Code:

First file:

```
from modules.proxy import *
set_proxy()
browser.get("website.com")
```

Second file:

```
def set_proxy():
   if proxy_type == "type1":
    global browser
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_DIR)
```

Result: " **name 'browser' is not defined** "

Comment: You need to give `browser` a default value so it will be set if the `if` condition fails.

Comment: From the python doc: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules

Comment: Where is `browser` supposed to come from in your example? Why do you think it _should_ be defined?

Comment: ...are you expecting `global browser` to refer to a module-scoped `browser` variable in the module _where it's called_, instead of the module _where it's defined_?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, that's exactly what I want to do

Comment: Ah. Yeah, that's not how things work. `global browser` in a function inside module A refers to `A.browser`, even if that function is imported into module B. (And you really should, in module A, initialize with `browser = None` before the function is ever called).

Comment: global variables are actually *global to the module*

Comment: but you shouldn't be using global variables like this to begin with.

Comment: Also, where is `browser` coming from in the first place?

Comment: @MadPhysicist it comes from second file and must be used in first file.

Answer (score 1):

you should return the browser variable value in the end of the function like this:

```
return browser
```

now get it main file like this:

```
browser = set_proxy()
browser.get("website.com")
```

Comment: Yup. That would do it

Answer (score -1):

You need to give a default value for `browser`.

File 1:

```py
browser: str = ""

def test():
    proxy: bool = True
    if proxy:
        global browser
        browser = "TEST"
```

File 2:

```py
import file1

file1.test()
print(file1.browser)
file1.browser = "TEST2"
print(file1.browser)
```

As expected the output are:

```
TEST
TEST2
```

Comment: this doesn't actually solve the problem

Comment: Seems to be working in my case checkout, do lemme know if I made some mistake.

Comment: You're not doing what OP is doing, but this could lead to a solution if you develop it

Comment: I know it's not a string. But I assumed he wanted this functionality, or going for modular approach. There are multiple ways to solve this problem.